# How to find numerically $\int_{0}^{1} w \langle \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{p}'\rangle \ du$ such $\nabla^2 w=0$ without solving the PDE for $w$ first?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, parabolic-pde

### Description

Let $w(x, \ y)$ be a function that satisfies laplace's equation

$$\nabla^2 w = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{on}  \  \Omega$$
$$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial n} =  \langle \mathbf{p}, \ \mathbf{t}\rangle \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{on}  \  \partial \Omega$$

$\mathbf{p}(u)$ parametrizes the closed curve $\partial \Omega$ in the plane, $\mathbf{t}$ is the tangent vector

$$\mathbf{p}(u) = \left(x(u), \ y(u)\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{with}  \ u  \in  \left[0,  \ 1 \right]$$
$$\mathbf{t} = \dfrac{1}{\|\mathbf{p}'\|} \cdot \mathbf{p}'$$

And set

$$w(\mathbf{p}(0)) = 0$$

My objetive is finding $J$

$$J = \int_{0}^{1} w \cdot \langle \mathbf{p}, \ \mathbf{p}'\rangle \ du$$

### Question

Is it possible to compute $J$ without solving the PDE ?

I mean, I don't actually need the values of $w$, only $J$. So I wondered if there's some way to do it

If it's not possible, any hint to help computing $J$ ?

### More

I tried to find some relation for $w$ on the boundary, but I don't know how I can proceed, or even if it's correct:

$$\nabla^2 w = \dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial n^2} = 0$$
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n} \left(\dfrac{ \langle\mathbf{p}, \ \mathbf{p}'\rangle}{\|\mathbf{p}'\|}\right)$$

The motivation is to compute the [torsion constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_constant) $\mathbb{J}$ of a beam:

$$\mathbb{J} = \int_{\Omega} x^2 + y^2 \ dx dy - J$$